# Como obtener la información de un objeto promise en angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic, cordova, ng-cordova

Realizando un **return** de una consulta en **SQLite** a una variable, el objeto queda como si estuviera encapsulado o no se como se llama, pero en la consola aparece como ***Promise***, dentro de el la información esta dentro de un ***value***, la cual esta dentro de un ***$$state***. Esta es la forma de la estructura del retorno del objeto:

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
  $$state: Object
  status: 1
  value: Object
    apellido: "Vides"
    cedula: 11223344
    facultad: "Tecno e Ing"
    nombre: "Diego"
    programa: "Sistemas"
    rol: "Estudiante"
    semestre: 10
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
angular.module('perfilEstu', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
   .controller('perfilEstudiante', perfilEstudiante)
   .factory('obtenerPerfil', obtenerPerfil);

perfilEstudiante.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerPerfil'];

function perfilEstudiante($scope, obtenerPerfil) {
   var Perfil, fila, i, l_perfil, db, sqlConsulta;
   Perfil = obtenerPerfil.datosPerfil();
   console.log(Perfil);       

};

obtenerPerfil.$inject = ['$cordovaSQLite', '$q'];

function obtenerPerfil($cordovaSQLite, $q) {

function datosPerfil(){       
    var sqlConsulta, db, perfil, datos, l_perfil, i, fila, deferObject;
    deferObject =  deferObject || $q.defer();
    sqlConsulta = "SELECT * FROM Estudiante"
    perfil = {};
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "unicesar.db" });
    perfil = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, sqlConsulta, []).then(function(resultado) {
        l_perfil = resultado.rows.length;
        for(i=0 ; i<l_perfil ; i++){
            fila = resultado.rows.item(i);
            datos = {
                cedula: fila.Cedula,
                nombre: fila.Nombre,
                apellido: fila.Apellido,
                rol: "Estudiante",
                facultad: fila.Facultad,
                programa: fila.Programa,
                semestre: fila.Semestre
            };
        }
        return datos;
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });   
    deferObject.resolve(perfil);
    return deferObject.promise; 
};    
  return {
      datosPerfil: datosPerfil
  };
};
```

Quisiera obtener el objeto de tal manera que lo pusiera de esta forma en la vista:

```
   $scope.Cedula = Perfil.cedula;
   $scope.Nombre = Perfil.nombre;
   $scope.Apellido = Perfil.apellido;
   $scope.Rol = Perfil.Rol;
   $scope.Facultad = Perfil.facultad;
   $scope.Programa = Perfil.programa;
   $scope.Semestre = Perfil.semestre;
```

Aquí dejo una imagen de lo que muestra la consola utilizando ***chrome://inspect***

[image: Obejeto Promise]

Gracias de ante mano por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola, ¿que información quieres devolver, la de todos los estudiantes o la de uno solo? Si es la de uno solo te faltaría un parametro para identificarlo y modificar la SQL para filtrar la consulta

Comment: @rsciriano, pues lo que quiero es poder mostrar el objeto en el html, pero es una Promise, y si uso then, me dice que no es una funcion, que solución me darias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás obteniendo un promise porque eso es lo que estás devolviendo desde la factoría por lo que para añadirlo al scope te bastaría con usar `then` en el controlador

```
function perfilEstudiante($scope, obtenerPerfil) {

    obtenerPerfil.datosPerfil().then(function(datos){
        $scope.Perfil = datos;
        console.log(datos);               
    })
};
```

Por otro lado la implementación del método con el que devuelves los datos de los perfiles no es correcta.

- La llamada a `deferObject.resolve(perfil)` se debería hacer cuando se devuelven los datos de la consulta
- Realmente no necesitas crear un `defered` para devolver los datos de la consulta porque puedes devolver directamente el promise de la ejecución de consulta encadenando en el `then` la transformación de datos
- Al hacer el bucle estás sobrescribiendo el valor de los datos por lo que solo devolverás el último

La implementación para devolver la lista de datos todos los perfiles aplicando lo que te comento se podría hacer de la siguiente manera

```
function obtenerPerfil($cordovaSQLite) {
    function datosPerfil(){       
        var sqlConsulta = "SELECT * FROM Estudiante";
        var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "unicesar.db" });
        return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, sqlConsulta, []).then(function(resultado) {
            var datos = [];
            for(i=0 ; i<resultado.rows.length ; i++){
                var fila = resultado.rows.item(i);
                datos.push({
                    cedula: fila.Cedula,
                    nombre: fila.Nombre,
                    apellido: fila.Apellido,
                    rol: "Estudiante",
                    facultad: fila.Facultad,
                    programa: fila.Programa,
                    semestre: fila.Semestre
                });
            }
            return datos;
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });    
    };

    return {
        datosPerfil: datosPerfil
    };
};
```

**P.D:** Creo que en vez de usar `factory`, deberías usar `service` porque realmente  no lo estás usando como una factoría. Prueba a registarlo como un servicio y debería seguir funcionando

Comment: Lo solucione de esta forma, [link](http://pastebin.com/V0ngynYR), de todos modos gracias